# LibreOffice Writer - weird math symbols from .docx files

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-office

I have LibreOffice 4.0 and Kubuntu 12.04. I have worked on a .docx file from Microsoft Office 2010 and I have used math symbols.

Now in Ubuntu I can't see those symbols well with LibreOffice Writer.
Here is a picture:
[image: The problem with the mathematic symbols in LibreOffice writer]

How can I solve it? If I enlarge the symbols from the picture above, I can see the function I wrote but in my file there many many symbols like those so I can't edit each of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by double-clicking the formula object, so L.O. Math will open it. Then, just do a single click inside the document page: L.O Math will close and the formula will be displayed with the default options (font, fontsize and everything else) of Math.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is terrific! However, it still doesn't let you resize the formula away from the default (which is still a major improvement over the way it first shows up.)